# Is $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have a Math example test to prepare for the real one, but I think my professor made an error:

**Question:** True or false?: For any $A$ set, $A \subseteq  \mathcal{P}(A)$.
**Answer:** False

But if $P(A)$ is the set of every subset of $A$, it also has to contain $A$ itself, as $A \subseteq A$. *(True by definition.)*
Thus my conclusion is that the answer should be true. I also considered that because $A$ is a set, and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is a set of sets, $A \not\subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, but {$A$} $\subseteq P(A)$, but that makes it that $A \subseteq ${$A$}, which implies that $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, doesn't it?

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: You can say $A \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $\{A\} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$, but these are different from $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$.

Comment: @angryavian, but if $A \subseteq$ {$A$} $ \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ does that not imply that $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$?

Comment: $A \subseteq \{A\}$ does not hold in general.

Comment: @L.F. because $A \in$ {$A$}, right?

Comment: The elements of the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ are themselves *subsets* of $A$. Of course $A$ is one such subset, which means that $A$ is *an element* of $\mathcal{P}(A)$. A **subset** of $\mathcal{P}(A)$ would be a *collection* of such elements, hence a *collection* of subsets of $A$, such as, say, $\{A\}$ or $\{\varnothing, A\}$.

Comment: Yes, $A \in \{A\}$ always holds.  On the other hand, $A \subseteq \{A\}$ holds if and only if $A = \varnothing$.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and the answer of @Bram28, you all have been very helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You indeed have $A \subseteq A$, but that only means that $A \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, not that $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$